# Upgrade a package that isn't in package.json

Tags: javascript, github, npm, lodash, yarnpkg

I get a warning from GitHub today, asking me to handle vulnerability caused by **lodash** that version is lower than 4.17.12 ([This GitHub Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qyc0.png)).

But I don't directly use lodash at this time, it's used by my dependencies. Though all of the dependencies use lodash 4.17.15, a 4.17.11 is still there. Followings are the outputs of `yarn list --pattern lodash`.

```
...more dependencies above
├─ cheerio@1.0.0-rc.3
│  └─ lodash@4.17.15
├─ global-tunnel-ng@2.7.1
│  └─ lodash@4.17.15
├─ istanbul-lib-instrument@3.3.0
│  └─ lodash@4.17.15
├─ jest-config@24.9.0
│  └─ lodash@4.17.15
├─ lodash@4.17.11
```

Then I tried `yarn remove lodash`, but got `error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.`

**So how do I upgrade the package(or remove it) that isn't in my packages.json?**

Comment: Because your dependencies depend on lodash, upgrading it might break them, so you are not allowed to do that.

Comment: I can't see any dependency use lodash 4.17.11, the outputs of `yarn list` seems to infers that they all use 4.17.15. Does that mean I should just wait for some packages to upgrade their lodash and cannot remove 4.17.11 by myself?

Comment: Using npm, not sure of yarn.  But you could update the node_modules manually,  eg. go into each directory where the module is installed, and do a `npm update lodash`,  as long as the sematic versioning is only a patch release it should work.  `4.17.11` -> `4.17.15` is a patch release, so you should be fine.   the package.json is likely to have `^4.17.x` or `4.17.11` etc, so updating should not break anything.

Comment: alternatively, delete the whole node_modules directory, and do an npm init inside your application.   If you have any `4.17.11` after this, then the developer has fixed it at `.11`, and that would seem strange for a patch release.  In fact even if the version was a `minor` release.. eg. `4.18.1` it should be fine too, unless the Dev's mucked up.. :)

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă  Upgrading a patch release should not break anything..  `4.17.11` -> `4.17.15` is a patch release.  That is the whole point of sematic versioning.  And in fact doing `minor` update should not break anything either.  Most dependencies in use are like -> `^X.Y.Z`, this means only updating to X is not automatic.

Comment: @Keith Upgrading might not break anything, but it's true only in this particular case.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă  It should be true in every case, take a look at the semver calculator -> https://semver.npmjs.com/  then place -> `^4.17.11` in the range field, notice how `4.17.15` is valid.  Of course if the Dev of package X had put `4.17.11` instead of `^4.17.11` then you shouldn't update, but then `npm update lodash` would not update anyway.   IOW: If `npm update lodash` works, it works because it should work (in every case).  If not the DEV's made a semver error and need contacting to fix.